# Is there any difference between CROSS APPLY and OUTER APPLY when creating a cartesian product?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cross-apply, outer-apply

When creating a cartesian product between two tables, is there any difference between `CROSS APPLY` and `OUTER APPLY`?

This may seem like a silly question given that without a relationship expressed between the tables, the right-hand table can't fail to satisfy the relation, but I'm respectful of what I don't know.

When I look at the execution plans with a simple test setup, they're identical [two index seeks feeding into Nested Loops (Inner Join)], but simple test setups can be deceptive.

Here's an example of what I mean ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/71053/1)). The setup:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.First (
    Id      INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name    NVARCHAR(100)
);
GO
DECLARE @n INT = 1;
WHILE @n < 10000
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.First (Name) VALUES ('First' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), @n));
    SET @n = @n + 1;
END
GO
CREATE INDEX IX__First__Name ON dbo.First(Name);
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Second (
    Id      INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name    NVARCHAR(100)
);
GO
DECLARE @n INT = 1;
WHILE @n < 10000
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Second (Name) VALUES ('Second' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), @n));
    SET @n = @n + 1;
END
GO
CREATE INDEX IX__Second__Name ON dbo.Second(Name);
GO
```

Using `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT      First.Id AS FirstId, Second.Id AS SecondId
FROM        First
CROSS APPLY Second
WHERE       First.Name IN ('First253', 'First3304')
AND         Second.Name IN ('Second6543', 'Second517');
```

Using `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT      First.Id AS FirstId, Second.Id AS SecondId
FROM        First
OUTER APPLY Second                                 -- <== Only change is here
WHERE       First.Name IN ('First253', 'First3304')
AND         Second.Name IN ('Second6543', 'Second517');
```

...both of which give me the expected four rows.

Plus various variations where either, or both, `IN` clauses return no matches:

```
-- No match in First
SELECT      First.Id AS FirstId, Second.Id AS SecondId
FROM        First
CROSS APPLY Second
WHERE       First.Name IN ('no match')
AND         Second.Name IN ('Second6543', 'Second517');

SELECT      First.Id AS FirstId, Second.Id AS SecondId
FROM        First
OUTER APPLY Second
WHERE       First.Name IN ('no match')
AND         Second.Name IN ('Second6543', 'Second517');

-- No match in Second
SELECT      First.Id AS FirstId, Second.Id AS SecondId
FROM        First
CROSS APPLY Second
WHERE       First.Name IN ('First253', 'First3304')
AND         Second.Name IN ('no match');

SELECT      First.Id AS FirstId, Second.Id AS SecondId
FROM        First
OUTER APPLY Second
WHERE       First.Name IN ('First253', 'First3304')
AND         Second.Name IN ('no match');

-- No match in either
SELECT      First.Id AS FirstId, Second.Id AS SecondId
FROM        First
CROSS APPLY Second
WHERE       First.Name IN ('no match')
AND         Second.Name IN ('no match');

SELECT      First.Id AS FirstId, Second.Id AS SecondId
FROM        First
OUTER APPLY Second
WHERE       First.Name IN ('no match')
AND         Second.Name IN ('no match');
```

...all of which give me the expected zero rows.

Comment: I give it high odds that the answer will require the use of `<!-- a filler comment or similar -->` to meet the minimum character length, "no" being too short... ;-)

Comment: `SELECT * FROM #A CROSS APPLY #A`, `SELECT * FROM #A OUTER APPLY #A` and `SELECT * FROM #A CROSS JOIN #A` are all synonymous. The different syntaxes will yield no benefits (or detriments).

Comment: With a condition like here `OUTER APPLY Second
WHERE       First.Name IN ('First253', 'First3304')
AND         Second.Name IN ('no match');` you are out-tricking the `OUTER`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference comes into play when applied table or table-valued function has no records:

```
SELECT      First.Id AS FirstId, Second.Id AS SecondId
FROM        First
OUTER APPLY (SELECT * FROM Second WHERE Second.Id = -1) Second
WHERE       First.Name IN ('First253', 'First3304');

2 rows returned


SELECT      First.Id AS FirstId, Second.Id AS SecondId
FROM        First
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM Second WHERE Second.Id = -1) Second
WHERE       First.Name IN ('First253', 'First3304');

0 rows returned
```

**In OP's own words:**

Not the way you're doing it, because conceptually you're filtering with `WHERE` after the `APPLY` (although the plans show the engine optimizing by doing it first); but if you explicitly filter first and then `APPLY` like this:

```
SELECT      First.Id AS FirstId, FilteredSecond.Id AS SecondId
FROM        First
CROSS APPLY (SELECT Id FROM Second WHERE Name IN ('xxx')) FilteredSecond 
WHERE       First.Name IN ('First253', 'First3304');
```

you'd see the difference because you'd get rows with NULLs with the `OUTER` but no rows with the `CROSS`.

Comment: But that's not a cartesian product anymore...?

Comment: OK. Cartesian product of a table with an empty table would be empty for cross apply and would contain records from the first table with outer apply.

Comment: In your examples you first create a cartesian product and then filter it through `WHERE`. Try leaving the Second table empty altogether and do an unconditional cartesian product.

Comment: More on cartesian products: [∅×B, A×∅, ∅×∅](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/51401). Theoretically, what `OUTER APPLY` does is not a cartesian product.

Comment: @Y.B True for the last comment. But the engine will decide in many (fairly simple) cases to deal with it exactly the same way as with a `JOIN`. Therefore - practically - it is the same very often :-D (you knew that assumably :-D +1 from my side)

Comment: So your answer is "Not the way you're doing it, because conceptually you're applying the filtering with `WHERE` after the `APPLY` (although the plans show the engine optimizing by doing it first); but if you explicitly filter first and then `APPLY` (like this: `SELECT First.Id AS FirstId, FilteredSecond.Id AS SecondId FROM First CROSS APPLY (SELECT Id FROM Second WHERE Name IN ('xxx')) FilteredSecond WHERE First.Name IN ('First253', 'First3304');`, you'd see the difference because you'd get rows with `NULL`s with the OUTER but no rows with the CROSS." Is that basically what you're saying?

Comment: Obviously I know that reorganizing like that would result in rows with `NULL`s, but the main point being "Not the way you're doing it, because conceptually you're applying the filtering after the product."

Comment: (With an `OUTER` I mean.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yep. :-)

Comment: Cool, let's move that into the answer and I'll have a think. But I think that's probably the answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's exactly what I've meant with *you are out-tricking the `OUTER`*

Answer (score 2):

Think of `CROSS APPLY` as related to an `INNER JOIN` and `OUTER APPLY` as related to a `LEFT JOIN`.

- CROSS / INNER will limit the result to rows from both sources, while
- OUTER / LEFT will return all rows of the first table and `NULLs` in case of no related row in the second source.

The difference is that `JOINs` link two resultset over a relation condition, while `APPLY` is called row-wise with values of a *current row*.

You can use `APPLY` to create computed values out of row values or (which is the main purpose) to call a TVF with row-values as parameters. Often you can see `APPLY` in connection with `XMLTypedVariable.nodes()`.

**Some thoughts about execution**
In simple cases (like above) the engine will decide to walk the same paths. But with more complex scenarios the differences can be huge.

Comment: That's all sort of high-level description stuff, which is fine, but I'm not seeing how it addresses the question...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see your point, but - as the OP uses conditions (`WHERE` clauses) the *cartesian product* might not be an *each-with-each* in any case. With a more complex query `APPLY` and `JOIN` will be handled differently. But it's hard to forecast, what the engine decides to be best...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, sorry, did not realise that you are the "OP" :-D